# Can't get data given in JSON with URL Localhost in browser to display on App with Javascript

Tags: javascript, java, html, angularjs, spring-boot

I have a  simple Spring boot application
Rest backend that returns JSON data. with the url:

```
"http://localhost:8806/test/C1"
```

At the moment I am only using the simple "test" as a test. It returns only a simple int only an int, and so on for the end C2 and C3.

I want to get these values in a loop and then assign those values to divs in my html. I have tried a lot of things I can't get to the values returned in the browser to work with them in my javascript file. I am sure this is a really simple thing.

```
@Entity
public class Asset {

    @Id
    private String id;
    private int value;


    public Asset(){
    }

    public Asset(String id, int value) {
        super();
        this.id = id;
        this.value = value;

    }

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public int getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    public void setValue(int value) {
        this.value = value;
    }
```

Controller:

```
package mindapp.inventorymanager.Assets;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;



@RestController
public class AssetController {

    @Autowired
    private AssetService assetService;


    @RequestMapping("/assets")
    public List<Asset>getAllAssets(){
        return assetService.getAllAssets();
    }

    @RequestMapping("assets/{id}")
    public int getAssetValue(@PathVariable String id){
        return assetService.getAssetValue(id);
    }

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.PUT, value = "/assets/{id}")
    public void updateAsset(@RequestBody Asset asset, @PathVariable String id){
        assetService.updateAsset(id, asset);
    }

    @RequestMapping("/test")
    public List<Asset> getAllTest(){
        return assetService.getAllTest();
    }
    @CrossOrigin
    @RequestMapping("/test/{id}")
    public int assetIDTest(@PathVariable String id){
            return assetService.test(id);
    }

}
```

Service:

```
package mindapp.inventorymanager.Assets;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Random;




@Service
public class AssetService {

    @Autowired
    private AssetRepository assetRepository;

    private List<Asset> assets = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(


    ));


    private List<Asset> assets1 = Arrays.asList(
            new Asset("C1",2),
            new Asset("C2",0),
            new Asset("C3",3)
    );


    private void generateNewListValues(){
        assets.clear();
        for(int i=1; i<=44;i++){
            Random randomGenerator = new Random();
            int randomInt = randomGenerator.nextInt(4);
            assets.add(new Asset("C"+i,randomInt));
        }
        assetRepository.save(assets);

    }

    public List<Asset> getAllAssets(){
        List<Asset> assets = new ArrayList<>();
        generateNewListValues();
        assetRepository.findAll().forEach(assets::add);
        return assets;
    }


    public int getAssetValue(String id){
        return assetRepository.findOne(id).getValue();
    }

    public void updateAsset(String id, Asset asset){
        assetRepository.save(asset);
    }


    public List<Asset>getAllTest(){
        return assets1;
    }
    public int test(String id){
        return  assets1.stream().filter(t->t.getId().equals(id)).findFirst().get().getValue();
    }


}
```

Repository Interface:

```
package mindapp.inventorymanager.Assets;

    import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;


    public interface AssetRepository extends CrudRepository<Asset, String> {
    }
```

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>[T] Inventory Management</title>
    <script src="js/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css"/>

</head>
<body>
<script src='https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.min.js'></script>
<script src='js/main.js'></script>

    <p id="value"></p>   <---That is where I want to show the value from 
                             http://localhost:8806/test/C1 with 
                              document.getElementById("walue").innerHTML=
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I think this is more of an Angular question.  I'd recommend adding that Tag to this question.

Comment: To get data from your webservice and write to html tag, you can using ajax to submit your request to server and get the json back. Then write it to your html tag. Here is an [example of using ajax](https://www.sitepoint.com/ajaxjquery-getjson-simple-example/)

Comment: You get any errors on browser when you make the call `http://localhost:8806/test/C1`, Are you getting any response out of it ?

Comment: PRATHAP- No I don't get any errors in the browser, when I do it I get the value that i want, that is just a number for example: 2 I just want to asign that 2 to a variable in my main js file so I can work with it.